# Keep column names from a data.frame in an output table in sql-server-2016

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2016

I have a table in `sql-server-2016`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempData (A int not null) 
 INSERT INTO #tempData   VALUES (0);
GO
```

Now I can call my R-script having the table as the input data (incl. column names):

```
EXECUTE  sp_execute_external_script
                @language = N'R'
              , @script = N'
                        df <- InputDataSet
                        df$B <- 1L'
              , @input_data_1 = N'SELECT * FROM #tempData'
              , @output_data_1_name = N'df'
WITH RESULT SETS (
    (A int not null, B int not null)
);
```

Returning:

```
A   B
0   1
```

as expected. But can I do the same without specifying the names, {A,B}, i.e. it will use the names from the `data.frame` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately with how BxlServer translates R in SQL Server today, you have to set the variable and type in RESULTS SET.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604368.aspx) it seems not possible.

```
WITH RESULTS SETS clause is mandatory if you are returning a result set from R . The specified column data types need to match the types supported in R (bit, int, float, datetime, varchar)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did read this, but this is not necessarily the same in my opinion. I know the set clause is mandatory because I need to specify the types, but this shouldn't exclude retrieving the names from the `data.frame`, or?